# How to get selected text from dropdown in selenium typescript

Tags: typescript, selenium, select, webdriver, dropdown

Hi i'm  trying to get the selected text from a dropdown box using selenium webdriver and typescript.
I have tried all(option:checked ,jquery etc) but it is not working .
How do we get the selected text using webelement chaining?
For example:
webelement parent= await driver.findElement(By.id("abc"));
var text=parent.------and get the selected option?
is it possible?

Comment: Found elements are HTMLElement, but there are more specific types which provide additional properties/methods, e.g. HTMLSelectElement.  You'll need to add a type guard so TS knows which type you are working with `if (el instanceof HTMLSelectElement) { console.log(el.selectedIndex) }`

Comment: i have given type as webElement so i want to use the parent weEelement (select box webelement) chained to find the option 'text' which is selected in that dropdown list..? Is it possible to do it in webElement type? since im providing a webelement paramter for that method @DaveMeehan

Comment: Please provide a clear example of the code that you are using.